# Stop werkzeug from messing my django debugging

Tags: python, django, werkzeug, django-debug-toolbar

For some https testing I needed to install Werkzeug. When accessing my site via https, Werkzeug decides that it must catch all exceptions, and takes over the role of the django-debug-toolbar and built-in django exception handling, by default, without even a configuration parameter:

```
Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

Well, I **am panicking** right now. I want my django-debug-toolbar back, specially when doing https, since what Werkzeug shows me is by comparison not enough.

How can I tell Werkzeug to stop being intrusive, and let exceptions reach django?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)'s RunServerPlus (`manage.py runserver_plus`) to test HTTPS. RunServerPlus enables the Werkzeug debugger by default and [looking at the source](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/runserver_plus.py#L339), there's no way to disable it. The same applies to [django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver](https://github.com/philippbosch/django-werkzeug-debugger-runserver).

I'd recommend opening an issue with the django-extensions project and/or trying [django-sslserver](https://github.com/teddziuba/django-sslserver) as an alternative.

---

In case I guessed incorrectly: If you're directly using Werkzeug's `run_simple`, call it with `use_debugger=False`. If you're directly using Werkzeug's `DebuggedApplication` middleware, well, stop using it - it's the source of your problems.